# Iteration on zipped array

Tags: ruby, arrays, iteration

Suppose we have two arrays

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
b = [1, 2, 3]
```

Now `a.zip(b)` gives me: `[["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3]]`.

How does:

```
a.zip(b).each do |i, j|
  puts "#{i} : #{j}"
end
```

take `i` as `"a"` and `j` as `1`, and so on? Please elaborate how this type of iteration works in Ruby.

Comment: What else would you expect?

Comment: I would expect `j` to be `nil` and `i` to be an array. I mean, if I used `each_with_index`, that's what I would expect right?

Comment: @MxyL: Fair enough. Ruby tries to be smarter than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`each` iterates through the array, taking the elements one by one: `["a", 1]`, `["b", 2]` ...

The element is assigned to the block parameter at each iteration.

Now the block parameter happens to be two (`i` and `j`). And the element is an array of two. In this situation, Ruby does "parallel assignment" and assigns the 2 array elements to the 2 parameters.

Compare to e.g.

```
a, b = [23, 42]    # a becomes 23, b becomes 42
```